# Implementing GetEnumerator in C++

Tags: .net, visual-c++, list, c++-cli, ienumerable

In C# i have the following class and it compiles just fine:

`class CustomItem
    {
    }`

```
class CustomList : IList<CustomItem>
{
    public CustomItem this[int index]
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public void CopyTo(CustomItem[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
    }

    public int Count { get { return 10; } }
    public int IndexOf(CustomItem item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Insert(int index, CustomItem item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void RemoveAt(int index) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Add(CustomItem item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void Clear() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public bool Contains(CustomItem item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return true; } }
    public bool Remove(CustomItem item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    public IEnumerator<CustomItem> GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

When i try the same in C++ i get several compiler errors:

`ref class CustomItemValue
    {
    };`

```
typedef CustomItemValue^ CustomItem;

ref class CustomList : public IList<CustomItem>
{
public:
    property CustomItem default[int]
    {
        virtual CustomItem get(int index) { return nullptr; }
        virtual void set(int index, CustomItem value) {}
    }
    virtual void CopyTo(array<CustomItem>^ array, int arrayIndex)
    {
    }

    property int Count { virtual int get() { return 10; } }
    virtual int IndexOf(CustomItem item) { throw gcnew NotImplementedException(); }
    virtual void Insert(int index, CustomItem item) { throw gcnew NotImplementedException(); }
    virtual void RemoveAt(int index) { throw gcnew NotImplementedException(); }
    virtual void Add(CustomItem item) { throw gcnew NotImplementedException(); }
    virtual void Clear() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    virtual bool Contains(CustomItem item) { throw gcnew NotImplementedException(); }
    property bool IsReadOnly { virtual bool get() { return true; } }
    virtual bool Remove(CustomItem item) { throw gcnew NotImplementedException(); }

    virtual IEnumerator<CustomItem>^ GetEnumerator() { throw gcnew NotImplementedException(); }
    virtual System::Collections::IEnumerator^ GetEnumerator()
    { throw gcnew NotImplementedException(); }
};
```

The error messages from the compiler are:

`.\mc.cpp(38) : error C2556: 'System::Collections::IEnumerator ^CustomList::GetEnumerator(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerator ^CustomList::GetEnumerator(void)'
        with
        [
            T=CustomItem
        ]
        .\mc.cpp(36) : see declaration of 'CustomList::GetEnumerator'
.\mc.cpp(38) : error C2371: 'CustomList::GetEnumerator' : redefinition; different basic types
        .\mc.cpp(36) : see declaration of 'CustomList::GetEnumerator'`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I wonder if you couldn't just inherit from Collection<CustomItem>, and just use overrides for the specific methods you want to change?

Comment: Sorry, but i did not find a class Collection<T> in .NET. As far as i know List<T> or Array<T> exists, but that's not exactly what i want. Thanks for your suggestion but i need this to access an existing list implementation in .NET. The list is implemented in C++ and i want to access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the Microsoft specific explicit override syntax for to override both GetEnumerator() methods:

```
virtual System::Collections::IEnumerator^ GetEnumerator2() = System::Collections::IEnumerable::GetEnumerator
{ throw gcnew NotImplementedException(); }

virtual IEnumerator<CustomItem>^ GetEnumerator()
{ throw gcnew NotImplementedException(); }
```

Note that I renamed the non-generic GetEnumerator method to GetEnumerator2 then specifies that it overrides System::Collections::IEnumerable::GetEnumerator. You can find out more about explicit override in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw0bbh51.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a clue in th error message. your GetEnumerator method returns System::Collections::IEnumerator^ while there is another method to this class that returns 
System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerator^ , this method is probably inherited from IList class.

Try to replace the return value with System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerator^.

Comment: Sorry, but i already tried it.
The problem is that the compiler complains about the second GetEnumerator definition, but without it the compiler complains about a missing function definition (because GetEnumerator is abstract).